# Why doesn't the recursion stop?

Tags: python, recursion

The following code:

```
def tri_recursion(k):
    if k > 0:
        result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
    return result


print("Recursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

Gives us:
1
3
6
10
15
21

My questions are: why does this code still execute after the first print which is 1? And why does it print 1 at all if the code gradually comes to the point where the result is 0, and in this scenario, it should just return the result, but not print?

Comment: _All_ the calls to `tri_recursion` happy _before_ any `print` calls. Then the `print`s happen in the reverse order than you might expect.

Comment: You should change the name of this question. It's a bit misleading, the recursion  hits is base case and does stop. It also returns the correct result of 21. You are asking a question about why the print statements are 'backwards' from what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because behind the scene, the compiler uses a stack data structure to simulate recursion and deliver the correct output.

Following is the recursion call stack showing return order of function calls (top to bottom)

```
tri_recursion(1)
tri_recursion(2)
tri_recursion(3)
tri_recursion(4)
tri_recursion(5)
tri_recursion(6)
```

Execution order of function calls(bottom to top) which is also followed by a print command

```
6 + 15 = 21
5 + 10 = 15
4 + 6 = 10
3 + 3 = 6
2 + 1 = 3
1 + 0 = 1
```

Check this [link](https://www.enjoyalgorithms.com/blog/recursion-explained-how-recursion-works-in-programming) for better understanding

Answer (score 3):

I find that it's easier to visualize the execution of a recursive function if you add `print`s at the start and end of the function, and you indent each `print` such that you can see where it is in the stack.

```
def tri_recursion(k):
    indent = " " * (6 - k)
    print(f"{indent}tri_recursion({k})")
    if k > 0:
        result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
        print(f"{indent}result: {result}")
    else:
        result = 0
        print(f"{indent}result: {result} (base case)")
    return result


print("Recursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

prints:

```
Recursion Example Results
tri_recursion(6)
 tri_recursion(5)
  tri_recursion(4)
   tri_recursion(3)
    tri_recursion(2)
     tri_recursion(1)
      tri_recursion(0)
      result: 0 (base case)
     result: 1
    result: 3
   result: 6
  result: 10
 result: 15
result: 21
```

You can see from the shape of the output that the function calls finish in reverse order from how they happened, because they're sort of sandwiched -- every time a recursive call is made, it's made *in the middle* of its caller, not at the very beginning or end.  The very first function call `(k=6)` doesn't return its result of 21 until its recursive call `(k=5)` has returned its result of 15.  The code doesn't stop when 1 is printed because all of those outer calls still haven't finished.